# Talker/Listener over SSH

Tags: ros, ros2, talker, ssh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I was wondering if it's possible to run the talker/listener examples with one of the machines being accessed by ssh.
Both my machines have ROS Eloquent installed and I would like to have my local machine A talking with the remote machine B, which I have access through ssh. I am using a VPN so that both machines are under the same network.
So far, I haven't been able to do this and so I would like to know if it's even possible.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349280/talker/listener-over-ssh/) by [anonymous53443](https://answers.ros.org/users/53443/anonymous53443/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2020-04-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-13**:\

> I am using a VPN so that both machines are under the same IP

You mean "in the same network", correct? Two machines with the same IP would not be able to communicate.

**Comment by [anonymous53443](https://answers.ros.org/users/53443/anonymous53443/) on 2020-04-13**:
yes, sorry. Already edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a really interesting question, and I personally have not done this myself. However, the ROS wiki on [Remote Machines](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleRemoteMachines) claims that it possible, with a few caveats.

1. Your ISP (internet service provider) allows for port forwarding.
2. The devices communicate with each other via Public IPs, which may change dynamically.
3. It has a lot of network configuration and setup outside of ROS, and the wiki link provided above tries to explain some of the problems faced.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [hashirzahir](https://answers.ros.org/users/53034/hashirzahir/) with karma: 228 on 2020-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous53443](https://answers.ros.org/users/53443/anonymous53443/) on 2020-04-13**:
This helps yes. It seems super complicated but possible.
Thank you very much!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-13**:
If you're using a VPN, port forwarding should not be needed.

@PedroACaldeira: you will have to make sure your VPN supports forwarding/routing UDP traffic though.